# Angular2 http POST request failing

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, ionic2

My service has two methods Get and Post. Get request is working but post request fails saying not authorized.

```
public getExercise(exerciseId): Observable<Exercise[]>{

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });

    return this.http.get(this.base_url + 'get_exercise/' + exerciseId + '/', options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

public saveRating(value, exerciseId): Observable<Exercise[]>{

    console.log(value + " " + exerciseId)

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    headers.append('Authorization','Basic')
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });

    return this.http.post(this.base_url + 'save_progress/' + exerciseId + "/" + value + "/", options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**Get:**

[image]

**Post:**

[image]

What am I doing wrong with Post method? I have original code from my angular1 application which works:

```
var url = "/api/exercises/save_progress/" + exerciseType + "/" + rating + "/";

              if($cookies.token){
                  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + $cookies.token;
              }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to angular's Http.post method is not the request options, but rather the body of the post request.

So, you should change your call to pass your request options as the third parameter to http.post, not the second.

eg:

```
return this.http.post(this.base_url + 'save_progress/' + exerciseId + "/" + value + "/", {}, options)
```

[see the Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html#!#post-anchor)

Comment: How can I modify then my request? `return this.http.post(this.base_url + 'save_progress/' + exerciseId + "/" + value + "/", body:any, options)` like this?

Comment: return this.http.post(this.base_url + 'save_progress/' + exerciseId + "/" + value + "/", {}, options) would work. Just have an empty object as your second parameter, since you don't have anything to post in the body